# Use of AES-NI in C#

Tags: c#, aes, aes-ni

I have a question,and I hope that I am correct here.
I want to use the AES-NI acceleration in a C# program. I did not find any good source about that and wanted to ask if this is possible and if there is any good source for information about that.
Also I wanted to ask, which key sizes are supported by AES-NI?

Comment: `AesCryptoServiceProvider` will use `AES-NI` on its own if availible

Comment: In principle AES-NI can speed up all key-sizes. But I didn't look at this specific implementation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set#Libraries

Comment: Perhaps I expressed myself a little bit wrong. My point is more not to use a library that uses AES-NI, but how I can use AES-NI direct in my code.

Comment: Check out this article for a C# implementation: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/09/18/utilizing-aes-new-instructions-aes-ni-in-a-windows-8-c-app

Answer (score 1):

AesCryptoServiceProvider is supposed to use AES-NI (and similar instruction sets). This is **not** in the documentation but after multiple benchmarks I have noticed ***significant*** (156 mbps with, 34 mbps without) performance improvements on AES-NI machines. So I guess it's safe to assume AES-NI is used.